# An error occurred while preparing SDK package SDK Platform Android 10: archive is not a ZIP archive

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

My sdk got deleted unfortunately from my machine. So I copied the whole SDK folder from another machine and copied it in mine and changed the sdk path in Android Studio and also in PATH environment variable. When I try to install SDK platforms from Android Studio, here's the error I got :

```
Packages to install: 
- SDK Platform Android 10 (platforms;android-29)
- SDK Platform Android R Preview (platforms;android-R)

Preparing "Install SDK Platform Android 10 (revision: 4)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-29_r04.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package SDK Platform Android 10: archive is not a ZIP archive
"Install SDK Platform Android 10 (revision: 4)" failed.
Preparing "Install SDK Platform Android 10 (revision: 4)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-29_r04.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package SDK Platform Android 10: archive is not a ZIP archive.
"Install SDK Platform Android 10 (revision: 4)" failed.
Preparing "Install SDK Platform Android R Preview (revision: 1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-R_r01.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package SDK Platform Android R Preview: archive is not a ZIP archive.
"Install SDK Platform Android R Preview (revision: 1)" failed.
Failed packages:
- SDK Platform Android 10 (platforms;android-29)
- SDK Platform Android R Preview (platforms;android-R)
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

**Android Studio version** : 3.4.1 in Windows 10

**P.S : I'm running Android Studio as Administrator with antivirus disabled in an open network connection.**

Comment: Try opening this link if it is internet error this might not open https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-29_r04.zip.

Comment: @VrushiPatel, It's getting downloaded in open connection.

Comment: @VrushiPatel, Could anything be done by manually downloading the zip?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that try from android studio itself.